# MacOS X - Change local Firebase deploy directory

Tags: macos, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

How can we change the directory Firebase deploys to for a specific project?

I want to be able to deploy multiple Firebase projects to different directories. Is this possible? Couldn't find any references in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can determine what directory the Firebase CLI deploys to Firebase Hosting by changing the `public` property in the `firebase.json` file in that directory.

See the [Firebase Hosting reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#public):

> ```
> "public": "app"
> ```
>
> **required** - The `public` setting tells the `firebase` command which directory to upload to Firebase Hosting. This directory must be inside the project directory and must exist. The default value is a directory named "public"